# In typst, how can I achieve the same like with `subequation` in LaTeX?

Tags: typesetting, typst

Consider the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
a = b\\
b = c\\
c = d
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

It results in:

[image: screenshot of a LaTeX-formula with three lines, where each line has its own unique number: (1a), (1b), (1c)]

How can I achive the same result in [typst](https://typst.app/docs/)?

In particular I need:

- every equation has its own number
- the equation numbers are enumerated by digit + letters

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if `{subequations}` command have direct equivalent in Typst but something similar can be made with counter [0](https://typst.app/docs/reference/meta/counter/).

Here is custom function in Typst:

```
// initialize new counter with custom key
#let c = counter("myequations")
// counter starts at 0, this will push it to 1
#c.step() 

// define function with sub-equation block
#let subequation(it) = block[
    // increase value of counter at sub-level
    #c.step(level: 2)

    // `#it` is content
    // `#h(1fr)` will move rest to the righ. 
    // `#c.display(pattern)` will render current counter based on provided pattern
    #it #h(1fr) (#c.display("1a"))
]

// use sub-equation block
#subequation[$a = b$]
#subequation[$b = c$]
#subequation[$c = d$]
```

Note: `#h(1fr)` [1](https://typst.app/docs/reference/layout/fraction/) is used instead of `\begin{align}`, for more advanced aligning check the layout section of reference [2](https://typst.app/docs/reference/layout/) if needed.